# Cannot apply CSS custom class in material design

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-6">
        <div style="margin-top: 50%">
            <md-input-container class="col-md-10"> 
            <label>
                Username
            </label> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.userName"> 
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div>
            <md-input-container class="col-md-10"> 
                <label>
                    Password
                </label> 
                <input ng-model="user.userPassword">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <a style="color: #2e98d6; border: 1px solid #2e98d6; text-transform: none; cursor: pointer;
           min-height: 36px; min-width: 150px; font-weight: 500; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 37px;
        padding: 0 20px;" class="md-button md-primary primary-btn pull-right" ng-click="doLogin()">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to apply custom css class to my angular material but it is not working but if I using inline style then I can.

Comment: Show your custom CSS class.  Showing us what works doesn't really help us to solve your issue.  Also, be sure to show us where you load material css AND where you load your custom css.

Comment: This just sounds like a specificity issue, which is why inline works.

Answer (score 0):

This works! So some of the styles were getting overridden by angular-material class, the simplest fix for this will be to add `!important` to the CSS properties that are getting overridden!

**How to check what is getting overridden?**

Open the console, select the element that you want to check, click the element and check for the CSS class you added, if any of the properties of that particular class have a `strikethrough` on them, then you add `!important` on that particular property!

**Note:** Since the stylesheets were not provided, I worked with the classes added by `angular-material` by default. Also Please ignore the Javascript part in the fiddle.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58z39p42/1/)

**CSS:**

```css
.button-customize{
  color: #2e98d6 !important; 
  border: 1px solid #2e98d6;
  text-transform: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 36px; 
  min-width: 150px; 
  font-weight: 500; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  border-radius: 37px !important;
  padding: 0 20px;
  }
```

Comment: Use specificity over `important!`. That includes the cascade.